# Spacing between columns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a project with bootstrap, and I have a problem with the alignment of the s columns. These apparently are not well aligned to the size of a specified column, so are spaces within the site.

I did not find some method that allows me to solve this. 
I leave an image below.

[Problem Image](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-problema-8986864.html)

Comment: Bootstrap provides certain column width only, if you require to have your own width you should use `Less` to adjust your desired size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting multiple rows' worth of columns within the same `<div class="row">`. That works if they're all the same height, but yours aren't. Bootstrap implements its grid system by making each cell `float: left`, which will give kind of funky results if some columns are taller than others. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqrJj/3/) where you can kind of see how it ends up positioning variable-height cells.

Instead, you probably want to do multiple separate `row`s, as shown in the second third of [that same example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqrJj/3/). Each `row` will start over at the left margin, fully under the `row` above it, which sounds like what you want.

Alternatively, you can add a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` as another way to start over at the left margin (as shown in the final third of that [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqrJj/3/)). This isn't as clean, but it can give you more flexibility to do really fancy stuff with your responsive layout. See the documentation for [responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

I'd go with multiple `row`s unless you really need the flexibility of responsive column resets.